# Adding a terms and conditions page to a Crystal Reports report

Tags: crystal-reports

In Visual Studio 2005 [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) we have a simple report to the back side of this report. I need to add our terms and conditions page.

How to insert or add a second report?

Or

I need to mention our terms and conditions page on back side of main report.

How can I add this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you have one detail per page, which is displayed in the Page Header, and you have nothing in the Details section, you could do the following:

In the Detail section, insert a second Detail second so that you'll have Detail A and Detail B.  Leave Detail A blank.  Put the Terms & Conditions image into Detail B, go to Format Section for Detail B, and check `New Page Before`.  The reasons for the two detail sections is sometimes CR doesn't respect New Page Before in a single Detail section.

Now, go to Format Section, and for the Page Header enter the following formula in the Suppress (No Drill-Down) formula editor:

```
PageNumber mod 2 = 0
```

You will now have one record printed in the page header, then a page with the watermark, then another page with a record in the page header, then a page with the watermark, etc.

You'll just need to make sure when printing to use full duplexing.

Comment: At present, i kept Page 1 - Details which i am retrieving from Database in Pageheader Section A


Terms & Conditions is one Single Image Piece
Just Above this Terms & Condition - Image, i have Field [MemberName] which is retrieved from Database.

Comment: If you need the Terms & Conditions printed on the back of every page, you may be better off just printing the Terms & Conditions onto a bunch of sheets of paper, and then printing your reports on those sheets.