# Crystal Reports - adding Terms & Conditions as extra page- and strike all previous formatting

Tags: crystal-reports

I've looked at a couple other posts (listed below) but I'm still looking for advice on this. I've got an order form and need to create an additional blank page at the end for Terms & Conditions. I have that part working but I can't figure out how to remove the formatting associated with the order form.

Current setup:
- Created a Report Footer with Terms & Conditions Listed.
- Edited the suppression formula for other sections (pagenumber=totalpagecount)

Problem:
The formatting gridlines & boxes from the order form carries over and I don't know how to suppress those so I just have text on a blank page. Image attached.

Thank you in advance for your brilliance.

[image]

Previously referenced:
[Adding an additional page to end of a Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232239/adding-an-additional-page-to-end-of-a-crystal-report)
[Adding a terms and conditions page to a Crystal Reports report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628582/adding-a-terms-and-conditions-page-to-a-crystal-reports-report)

Comment: Show us your design, you have probably lines/boxes in this section aswell

Comment: @KuKeC yes, that's what was wrong. Thank you. I ended up creating individual line objects, changing the color to white, and pasting them over the black lines. Is there a better/less tedious way to have done that?

Comment: Show me your design in question and i will see